# Localization in Rotavita.ActionAsPdf not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, wkhtmltopdf

The Details method returns the localized view but GeneratePdf Method doesn't.

```
public ActionResult GeneratePdf(long id, long userId)
{
     return new ActionAsPdf("Details", new { id = id, userId = userId }) { FileName="pdf.pdf", PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape};
}
public ActionResult Details(long id, long userId)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning View in Details method, return ViewAsPdf to resolve the issue.

```
public ActionResult Details(long id, long userId)
{
    return new ViewAsPdf() { FileName = "pdf.pdf", PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape };
}
```